# Angular Material Design - Fixed Side Bar

Tags: angular, angular-material2

How do i create a fixed side bar and a scrollable content. Like shown on their website.

https://material.angular.io/components/

I tried using this - https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples

But it forces you to set the width and the height which i dont want to do as i want to use the full browser width and it be responsive.

```
.example-sidenav-fab-container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
```

Comment: What are you talking about? it doesn't force you to set the width and height. The `.example-sidenav-fab-container` css is for the CONTAINER of the sidenav and content. The height of the sidenav always fills its container. The width, by default, fts the size of the content. Read their [documentation](https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/overview#sizing-the-sidenav)

Comment: If you try the example in plunker and remove the width and the height. the functionality of sidenav being fixed with scroll-able content does not work. @JunKang Look here https://plnkr.co/edit/4abHHqpiH2xkvFynLTk9?p=preview. The side nav is not fixed. All did was add more content and remove the width and height.

Comment: and if u look at this page of their official website. https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview the functionality they have of fixed side bar and content with both being seperatly scrollabble, This is what im after.

Comment: So apprently it is a bug where position:fixed is not working. It is fixed and will be updated, a temp fix is listed at the bottom https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/998

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Position fixed does not work on the side nav as expected so you must set the width and height to fixed amount for the side nav to be fixed with a scrollable content.

Issue is documented and meant to be fixed in next release.
https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/998

Temporary fix:

```
.mat-sidenav-content,
.mat-sidenav-container,
.mat-drawer-content {
    transform: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For `<mat-sidenav>` only (not `<mat-drawer>`) fixed positioning is supported. It can be enabled by setting the fixedInViewport property. Additionally, top and bottom space can be set via the fixedTopGap and fixedBottomGap. These properties accept a pixel value amount of space to add at the top or bottom.

Like this [Expample](https://stackblitz.com/angular/oyxyqxpopjvm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fsidenav-fixed-example.html)